# find words in txt files Python 3

Tags: python

I'd like to create a program in python  3 to find  how many time a specific words appears in txt files and then to built an excel tabel with these values.
I made this function but at the end when I recall the function and put the input, the progam doesn't work. Appearing this sentence: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

```
def wordcount(filename, listwords):   
    try:

    file = open( filename, "r")   

    read = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    for x in listwords:
        y = x.lower()
        counter = 0
        for z in read:
            line = z.split()
            for ss in line:
                l = ss.lower()
            if y == l:
                 counter += 1

        print(y , counter)
```

Now I try to recall the function with a txt file and the word to find

```
 wordcount("aaa.txt" , 'word' )
```

Like output I'd like to watch

```
word 4
```

thanks to everybody !

Comment: You have indentation errors. In particular, the `try` statements requires an indented block following it. Consider using an IDE such as [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) to give you syntax hints.

Comment: You need to pass in 'word' as a list, `wordcount("aaa.txt", ["word"])`. Also, as @ArneRecknagel said you need to fix the indentation in the `try` block and add an `except` block after.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example you can use to find the number of time a specific word is in a text file;

```
def searching(filename,word):
    counter = 0
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if word in line:
                print(word)
                counter += 1
    return counter

x = searching("filename","wordtofind")
print(x)
```

The output will be the word you try to find and the number of time it occur.

Answer (score 0):

As short as possible:

```
def wordcount(filename, listwords):
    with open(filename) as file_object:
        file_text = file_object.read()
        return {word: file_text.count(word) for word in listwords}

for word, count in wordcount('aaa.txt', ['a', 'list', 'of', 'words']).items():
    print("Count of {}: {}".format(word, count))
```

Getting back to mij's comment about passing `listwofwords` as an actual list: If you pass a string to code that expects a list, python will interpret the string as a list of characters, which can be confusing if this behaviour is unfamiliar.